# Why this compiler error when mixing C# ValueTuple and dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, roslyn, c#-7.0

When using `ValueTuple` and dynamic object, I received this weird *CS8133 error*. I am passing dynamic object as input and taking ValueTuple as output. Why are they affecting each other.

```
public static (string, string) foo(dynamic input)
{
    return ("", "");
}

public void foo_test()
{
    dynamic input = new { a = "", b = "" };
    (string v1, string v2) = foo(new { a = "", b = "" }); //compiles fine
    (string v3, string v4) = foo(input); //CS8133 Cannot deconstruct dynamic objects
    var result = foo(input);  //compiles fine
}
```

Edit: 
The error message is: `CS8133   Cannot deconstruct dynamic objects`

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: `foo(input)` -> `foo((object)input)`

Comment: @PetSerAl but why. Why is the compiler only reporting error on the second invocation

Comment: @XiaoguoGe Call to `foo` have `dynamic` argument (`input`), thus it done by dynamic binding and have `dynamic` return type, but not `(string, string)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [the feature spec](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/deconstruction.md#resolution-of-the-deconstruct-method):

> The resolution is equivalent to typing `rhs.Deconstruct(out var x1, out var x2, ...);` with the appropriate number of parameters to deconstruct into. It is based on normal overload resolution. This implies that rhs cannot be dynamic and that none of the parameters of the Deconstruct method can be type arguments. ...

The part that is important is the `var`.
In normal overload resolution, we can infer the type from the `Deconstruct` methods that are discovered. But with dynamic method invocation, you cannot get compile-time type information, so the `var` types are necessarily left un-inferred (ie. that's an error).

More generally, this is why you cannot use `out var` on a dynamic invocation (what is the `var` type of the out var local?).